# Add bootstrap tooltips via jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

How would I loop over some links in a div and apply the Bootstrap tooltips to them based on their title text. So for example I would need this:

```
<a href="#" tile="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" tile="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" tile="link3">Link 3</a>
```

To become this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" tile="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" tile="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" tile="link3">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it:

```
$('a').each(function () {

    $(this).data('toggle', 'tooltip');
    $(this).data('placement', 'bottom');

    $(this).tooltip()
});

//for disable :
$('a').each(function () { 
    $(this).removeAttr("data-toggle");
    $(this).removeAttr("data-placement");
    $(this).tooltip('disable');
});
```

Comment: Thats perfect. So I perform this function on page scroll when the layout changes but also need to toggle them OFF again in the ELSE function.

Comment: I tried to add the disable in the ELSE statement and that is being applied completely. So they are always disabled?

Comment: you can re-enable again by $(this).tooltip('enable');

Comment: Yes that worked. Only problem now is it is ignoring the placement bottom and defaulting to top for some reasons?

Comment: Any ideas foadabd?

Comment: @j00m i update code for remove placement and toggle attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```js
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr({
    'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
    'data-placement': 'bottom',
  }).tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<a href="#" title="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" title="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" title="link3">Link 3</a>
```